# Can't Fetch the json String Key?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

Please refer the following JSON format. This is my JSON response from the server. I can get the `{ myArrayList : ... }` by using the key `RESPONSE` But i can't get the `id` by using the key `myArrayList`. Please help me find the solution.

> {"RESPONSE":"{\"myArrayList\":[{\"id\":1,\"title\":\"Ms.\",\"firstName\":\"jana\",\"middleName\":\"jana\",\"lastName\":\"jana\",\"emailId\":\"\",\"officalLandline\":\"43545346\",\"mobile\":\"34543534534\",\"fax\":\"\",\"skypeId\":\"\",\"gtalk\":\"\",\"windowsLive\":\"\",\"faceBook\":\"\",\"linkedIn\":\"\",\"website\":\"\",\"remarks\":\"\",\"contactSource\":\"External Reference\",\"dob\":\"Oct 3, 2011 12:00:00 AM\",\"preferredTimeZone\":\"GMT-11:00\",\"lastEditedBy\":\"admin\",\"organisation\":\"\",\"contactType\":\"Retailer\",\"shareAll\":null,\"status\":null,\"modeOfCommunication\":\"mobile\",\"createdBy\":\"admin\",\"createdTime\":\"Oct 11, 2011 11:21:00 AM\",\"lastModifiedBy\":null},{\"id\":2,\"title\":\"Mr.\",\"firstName\":\"sugadev\",\"middleName\":\"sugadev\",\"lastName\":\"jeyamani\",\"emailId\":\"jsugadev22@gmail.com\",\"officalLandline\":\"34566744467\",\"mobile\":\"2434234545\",\"fax\":\"\",\"skypeId\":\"\",\"gtalk\":\"\",\"windowsLive\":\"\",\"faceBook\":\"\",\"linkedIn\":\"\",\"website\":\"\",\"remarks\":\"\",\"contactSource\":\"Partner Reference\",\"dob\":\"Oct 2, 2011 12:00:00 AM\",\"preferredTimeZone\":\"West Samoa Time\",\"lastEditedBy\":\"admin\",\"organisation\":\"\",\"contactType\":\"Retailer\",\"shareAll\":null,\"status\":null,\"modeOfCommunication\":\"mobile\",\"createdBy\":\"admin\",\"createdTime\":\"Oct 11, 2011 11:22:52 AM\",\"lastModifiedBy\":null}]}"}

Comment: Could you try formatting the object more nicely (i.e. with indentation and line breaks) so that we can see what we're actually dealing with here?

Comment: hi please see my edited format.... i strucked to get the "id" and title....

Answer (score 1):

The key myArrayList would give you an array of dictionaries. Store it in an array. Then use objectAtIndex on that array to get individual dictionaries and then use the key "id" on each to fetch your value.

Comment: i tried like this jsonValue = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
 NSLog(@"jsonValue:%@",[jsonValue objectForKey:@"RESPONSE"]);
 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [jsonValue objectForKey:@"RESPONSE"];
 NSLog(@"dict:%@",[dict objectForKey:@"myArrayList"]);
but it shows exception

Comment: Try NSDictionary instead of NSMutableDictionary

Comment: What is your exception and to which object? What does your final NSLog statement above show? when you do an objectForKey using myArrayList, you get a ARRAY not a dictionary. Remember that.

Comment: And yes, check your formatting. Please use one of the many online JSON viewers to actually see if you have a valid JSON object in the first place too.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is not properly formatted.

Try this:

```
{"RESPONSE":{"myArrayList":[{"id":1,"title":"Ms.","firstName":"safd","middleName":"afdsaf","lastName":"asfas","emailId":"","officalLandline":"43545346","mobile":"34543534534","fax":"","skypeId":"","gtalk":"","windowsLive":"","faceBook":"","linkedIn":"","website":"","remarks":"","contactSource":"External Reference","dob":"Oct 3, 2011 12:00:00 AM","preferredTimeZone":"GMT-11:00","lastEditedBy":"admin","organisation":"","contactType":"Retailer","shareAll":null,"status":null,"modeOfCommunication":"mobile","createdBy":"admin","createdTime":"Oct 11, 2011 11:21:00 AM","lastModifiedBy":null},{"id":2,"title":"Mr.","firstName":"asdf","middleName":"af","lastName":"fd","emailId":"sdfa@gmail.com","officalLandline":"34566744467","mobile":"2434234545","fax":"","skypeId":"","gtalk":"","windowsLive":"","faceBook":"","linkedIn":"","website":"","remarks":"","contactSource":"Partner Reference","dob":"Oct 2, 2011 12:00:00 AM","preferredTimeZone":"West Samoa Time","lastEditedBy":"admin","organisation":"","contactType":"Retailer","shareAll":null,"status":null,"modeOfCommunication":"mobile","createdBy":"admin","createdTime":"Oct 11, 2011 11:22:52 AM","lastModifiedBy":null}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your JSON:

```
{
  "RESPONSE":
    "{
        "myArrayList":[
            {
                "id":1,
                "title":"Ms.",
                "firstName":"safd",
                "middleName":"afdsaf",
                "lastName":"asfas",
                "emailId":"",
                "officalLandline":"43545346",
                "mobile":"34543534534",
                "fax":"",
                "skypeId":"",
                "gtalk":"",
                "windowsLive":"",
                "faceBook":"",
                "linkedIn":"",
                "website":"",
                "remarks":"",
                "contactSource":"External Reference",
                "dob":"Oct 3, 2011 12:00:00 AM",
                "preferredTimeZone":"GMT-11:00",
                "lastEditedBy":"admin",
                "organisation":"",
                "contactType":"Retailer",
                "shareAll":null,
                "status":null,
                "modeOfCommunication":"mobile",
                "createdBy":"admin",
                "createdTime":"Oct 11, 2011 11:21:00 AM",
                "lastModifiedBy":null
                },
                {
                    "id":2,
                    "title":"Mr.",
                    "firstName":"asdf",
                    "middleName":"af",
                    "lastName":"fd",
                    "emailId":"sdfa@gmail.com",
                    "officalLandline":"34566744467",
                    "mobile":"2434234545",
                    "fax":"",
                    "skypeId":"",
                    "gtalk":"",
                    "windowsLive":"",
                    "faceBook":"",
                    "linkedIn":"",
                    "website":"",
                    "remarks":"",
                    "contactSource":"Partner Reference",
                    "dob":"Oct 2, 2011 12:00:00 AM",
                    "preferredTimeZone":"West Samoa Time",
                    "lastEditedBy":"admin",
                    "organisation":"",
                    "contactType":"Retailer",
                    "shareAll":null,
                    "status":null,
                    "modeOfCommunication":"mobile",
                    "createdBy":"admin",
                    "createdTime":"Oct 11, 2011 11:22:52 AM",
                    "lastModifiedBy":null
                    }
                ]"
            }
```

as you may see, you have some bad formating, i.e the 3rd quotation mark shouldn't be there, you have a quotationmark after the end-array-bracket, and there seems to be missing a } at the end..

Comment: please see my edited question that response string i got from the server

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all,

I found the solution that i got the `{"myArrayList"...}` as a string thats the reason i can't get the rest of the keys properly

i Found by using this coding

```
NSDictionary *responseDate = [response objectForKey:@"responseData"];
If ([[responseData objectForKey:@"results"] isKindOfClass [NSArray class]]) {
NSArray *resultsArray = [responseData objectForKey:@"results"];
   ... do other things to get to each result in the array ...
}
else if ([[responseData objectForKey:@"results"] isKindOfClass [NSDictionary class]]) {
 // it looks like each individual result in returned in a NSDictionary in your example
 ... do the things to handle the single result ...
} 
else {
 // handle no results returned
}
```

And i took the result as per normal way by using webService developer

Thank you for you answers friends :)